# How to move a file in a folder with timestamp in mule 4

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4, anypoint-studio, mule-connector

I have a file which is flatfile I want to move to a specific folder. Please help me in achieving this.
I tried the below expression
targetPath="#['C:\workspace\file\src\main\resources\move' ++ (as DateTime as String {format: 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'})]"

Comment: What is the issue? Are there any errors? Please share the full operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the SFTP connector Move operation:

```
<sftp:move config-ref="file" sourcePath="#[vars.source]" targetPath="C:\workspace\file\src\main\resources\move" createParentDirectories="true" renameTo="#['myfile ' ++ (now() as String {format: 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssX' }++ ".dat")]"/>
```

The `<file:move>` operation uses the same attributes.
Warning: using colons (`:`) in file names is not valid in Windows filesystems.

Comment: Hi @aled
I tried the above expression too as you said the output will be "move20230423234613"  but i want inside move folder->"myfile.dat 20230423231233", please seguest

Comment: the expression is always creating folder and then moving the file Please suggest
how to move the file inside "move folder" then add the timestamp to it.

Comment: Please share the details of the operation you are using.

Comment: and also the expected format of the destination file. Do you want it to have a space after `myfile.dat`?

Comment: sftp- move connector 
myfile 2023-04-24T12:57:22.941Z.dat is the expected output inside my folder.

Comment: Updated solution. Note that you should have provided the details from the beginning.

Comment: Thank you so much it helped a lot.. Surely I will keep this in mind while asking questions. 
i was not able to get it at all and I had to rename it after storing. thanks again.